# Image button Transparency Problem in WPF

Tags: wpf

I want to apply transparency to a button which contains an image, but button's transparent seems when application start. How can ı do this?

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Name="btnClose" 
                        BorderBrush="Transparent" 
                        Background="Transparent"
                        BorderThickness="0" Click="btnClose_Click">
                    <Image  Source="close.ico" ></Image>
</Button>
```

and what is the method that close the-

Comment: Did you hit submit by accident?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - To set the overall transparency of the button you should set the `Opacity` property to something between 0 and 1. Not sure what you want to do at application start but if you set values in XAML those are automatically applied at startup. If you want to animate it to become visible please clarify.

2 - To only show the image you can override the template of the button to only show its content, add this to the Button:

```
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <ContentPresenter />
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

3 - To exit the application when the button is clicked add this to the handler of the click event:

```
App.Current.Shutdown();
```

Comment: My Second Question is what is the method that close the application?

Comment: That should be `App.Current.Shutdown()`

Comment: I want picture to only appear ,button not

Comment: Glad that helped. By the way, there is this checkmark outline on the left, if my answer resolved your problem you can click that to mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

When I tested your code here the button was "shown" only when the cursor was over it.

Another way to do this is use only the **Image** control and it's **MouseLeftButtonDown** event.
Put the `this.Close();` command in it and you have a image that closes the form when *clicked*.